# Interactive services dialog detection in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, cruisecontrol.net

I have installed cc.net 1.4.3 version on Windows Vista. But It keeps giving me Interactive services dialog detection when I execute tests. I even have disabled the interactive services from services panel. but still getting this.

Any idea how to get rid of this problem 
regards
Sam

Answer (score 2):

No easy fix that you can do.  The service is trying to pop up UI on the user desktop.  In XP this worked because services and the first user log on both run in session 0.  In Vista, services run in session 0 and the first user runs in session 1, so there is no way for a service to directly show UI to the user.  This was due to security issues - search for Win32 Shatter Attack to get more details, but basically an untrusted user could send malformed window messages to the services, and in some cases could even cause arbitrary code execution.

You can disable it altogether by disabling the "Interactive Services Detection" service on the system.  But you won't see notifications at all, and this will disable it for all interactive services.  Best approach is to complain to the vendor to update their software for Vista.

EDIT: And the software is broken on XP when multiple users are logged on and the active user isn't in session 0.